UnknownHostException after upgrade from Pac4j 5.7.6 to 5.7.7
I've upgraded from 5.7.6 to 5.7.7 and now I got a java.net.UnknownHostException:
My URL is: keycloak.localhost (for Docker container):
oidcConfig.baseUri = http://keycloak.localhost
oidcConfig.discoveryURI = http://keycloak.localhost/realms/gixx/.well-known/openid-configuration

I got the exception here:
org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration.internalInit(OidcConfiguration.java:198)

For Docker I'm trying to use a subdomain, but it seems it has been changed in 5.7.7. Can this be fixed?
Edit:
Same issue occurs in:
org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator
In Function: validate
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: keycloak.localhost

Can this be fixed to use also for testing URL´s like keycloak.localhost ?

This is quite strange as v5.7.7 is just a minor upgrade from v5.7.6!
What's the full stack trace?
